# Optical measurement of CO2 with LED

Tags: led, sensor, infrared

This [teardown](https://www.fictiv.com/blog/posts/netatmo-weather-station-teardown-part-1-outdoor-module) of a personal weather station shows an LED which is apparently used for detection of carbon dioxide with an accuracy of +/-5% within 0-5000ppm: 
[image]

All the commercially  available carbon dioxide sensors I've found retail for above 100USD, so a low-power, low-cost sensor like this is appealing for IOT sensing (eg greenhouse monitoring). However, I haven't been able to find any information on this strange dome-shaped LED.

Another view:

[image]

The teardown says the LED is an infrared emitter/receiver pair: in the enclosure, it is pointed at a white surface, and it measures how much IR light is reflected from the white surface to calculate the CO2. This [paper](https://orbit.dtu.dk/files/146097852/Untitled.pdf) implies the sensor is an NDIR LED, and that its accuracy varies linearly with temperature, but doesn't go into specifics, and searching for NDIR LEDs shows expensive modules with waveguides.

Where could I find an LED like this? What specifications should I look for in an LED (eg spectrum, dome)?

Why haven't other companies done this, if it's so cheap and good?

Comment: https://www.co2meter.com/blogs/news/6010192-how-does-an-ndir-co2-sensor-work

Comment: how do you know they aren't using this part?

Comment: Most (all?) of the modules I've seen on Digikey/Mouser/the web use waveguides, whereas this detector just uses an LED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there was a mistake in the teardown. The "optical CO2 sensor" is in fact an RGB LED. The outdoor weather station does not measure CO2 at all.

The 5% accurate CO2 sensor mentioned in the Netatmo documentation is this chunky module in the internal weather station: 
[image]

I reached out to Fictiv and they said they would update the teardown. I guess the lesson is, if something sounds too good to be true (eg measuring CO2 with an LED), it probably is!

Comment: if you find out more information on this I'd be keen to here about it. To me it looks a bit like a gas thermal conductivity sensor if that's any help. Measuring gas thermal conductivity can allow you to estimate CO2 content providing the rest of the content is O2 and N2 i.e. air. If there is methane or propane thrown into the mix it becomes much more difficult (you might guess my company makes gas analysers!)

Answer (score 3):

To measure CO2 accurately you need to monitor the spectrum at 4300 nm AND monitor the spectrum at 3900 nm. The first spectral value gives you an indication of how much CO2 attenuates an optical signal that HAS to be reliably broadband in its spectrum. The second spectral value isn’t affected by CO2 hence, it can be used as a reference measurement should the “reliably broadband” light emission lower its intensity (due to temperature or ageing or other contamination in the signal path).

So, ask yourself; does the circuit/module you have uncovered do what I have described above or, does it do it cheaply and with subsequent inaccuracy?

Comment: The CO2 sensor that I worked with in the long ago measured CO2 + H2O at one wavelength, and just H2O at another, and then subtracted out the H2O signal.  I don't think I ever knew the wavelengths, though.

Comment: I think the circuit I uncovered measures CO2 cheaply and inaccurately, but that doesn't mean it's not worthwhile. I found a paper that suggests you can get the advertised accuracy (5% between 0-5000ppm) if you measure temperature and apply a correction factor, so I'm interested in finding a suitable LED and using a temperature sensor to get a cheap and accurate result.

Comment: I answered why it was cheap and hinted that it probably wasn’t that good. I also told you what the more expensive and accurate sensors use. Product recommendations are an off topic subject on this site.

Comment: Beyond product recommendations, would you have any advice on identifying the LED on the circuit board?

Comment: You’ll just have to slog through google searching with the words you used in your question. Or maybe try contacting the PCBs supplier. I genuinely don’t know what part it is.

Comment: A dual wavelength NDIR Gas detector like the one you describe will use a filament light source, optical filters and some NIR-sensors, all of which are quite expensive components (also in volumes), especially compared to the Bosch etc environmental sensor chips for the drones and wearable markets - the chance that this will show up in a evaluation module like the one in OP is slim. Quite slim. Disclaimer; Optical gas detection is what I do.

Comment: @MrGerber Hamamatsu make an IR LED that covers the 3900 nm and 4300 nm range and that is hence more attractive in terms of power dissipation and speed of modulation. Not cheap though.

Comment: Yeah, there was supposed to be a "typically" in the first sentence there. I have looked at them, but I don't know of anyone using them commercially yet. At least not in big scale in detection products, might be used in analysis. Didn't know you did that, btw! Where do you work?

Comment: @MrGerber I’m an engineer on natural gas analysis stuff. There is a guy from Italy using them who sometimes asks questions on stuff. If you don’t find him I’ll try to remember to comment you in if he asks a question or I stumble across him.